# pd to_datetime not converting DDMMMYYYY dates to datetime in python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Here's what my data looks like. As you can see, there are some columns with DDMMMYYYY format, some are NaN and some are standard DD/MM/YYYY format.

```
completion_date_latest      15/03/2001
completion_date_original    15/03/2001
customer_birth_date_1       30/11/1970
customer_birth_date_2       20/11/1971
d_start                      01Feb2018
latest_maturity_date        28/02/2021
latest_valuation_date       15/03/2001
sdate                              NaN
startdt_def                        NaN
obs_date                     01Feb2018
```

I want to convert them to datetime fields. I have a list of columns in a list called `varlist2`, and I'm looping through them to a) remove the NA's and b) convert to datetime using the `to_datetime` function:

```
for m in range (0,len(varlist2)):
    date_var = varlist2[m]
    print('MM_Dates transform variable: ' + date_var)

    mm_dates_base[date_var] = pd.to_datetime(mm_dates_base[date_var], errors='ignore', dayfirst=True)
    mm_dates_base[date_var] = mm_dates_base[date_var].fillna('')
```

However, when I check my output, I get this, where d_start and obs_date haven't been converted. Any idea why this might be the case and what I can do to fix it?

```
In [111]: print(mm_dates_base.iloc[0])
completion_date_latest      2001-03-15 00:00:00
completion_date_original    2001-03-15 00:00:00
customer_birth_date_1       1970-11-30 00:00:00
customer_birth_date_2       1971-11-20 00:00:00
d_start                               01Feb2018
latest_maturity_date        2021-02-28 00:00:00
latest_valuation_date       2001-03-15 00:00:00
sdate                                          
startdt_def                                    
obs_date                              01Feb2018
```

Any ideas how I can treat the DDMMMYYYY dates at the same time?

Comment: This set of data converted fine for me. I suspect you might have a problem else were in your dataset.  Using Pandas version '0.22.0' with statement `pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)`.

Comment: Do you need replace `NaN`s in all columns with `NaN`s only? Or need replace all `NaN`s, also if between datetimes? Because if replace dates in datetimes, get mixed data - strings with datetimes and if need apply some datetimelike function all failed. so best dont use `fillna('')` here.

Answer (score 1):

You can select all columns define by column `varlist2` to `DataFrame`, then use `apply` + [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) with `errors='coerce'` for convert problematic formats to `NaT`s if not possible converting. Last replace `NaT`s by [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) and assign back:

```
df1 = mm_dates_base[varlist2].apply(pd.to_datetime, errors='coerce', dayfirst=True)
df2 = mm_dates_base[varlist2].apply(pd.to_datetime, errors='coerce', format='%d%b%Y')

mm_dates_base[varlist2] = df1.combine_first(df2)
print (mm_dates_base)
  completion_date_latest completion_date_original customer_birth_date_1  \
0             2001-03-15               2001-03-15            1970-11-30   

  customer_birth_date_2    d_start latest_maturity_date latest_valuation_date  \
0            1971-11-20 2018-02-01           2021-02-28            2001-03-15   

  sdate startdt_def   obs_date  
0   NaT         NaT 2018-02-01
```

Another faster solution is loop each column:

```
for col in varlist2:
    a = pd.to_datetime(mm_dates_base[col], errors='coerce', dayfirst=True)
    b = pd.to_datetime(mm_dates_base[col], errors='coerce', format='%d%b%Y')
    mm_dates_base[col] = a.combine_first(b)
```

Fast compare:

```
#[100 rows x 10 columns]
mm_dates_base = pd.concat([df] * 100, ignore_index=True)
In [41]: %%timeit
    ...: 
    ...: for col in varlist2:
    ...:     a = pd.to_datetime(mm_dates_base[col], errors='coerce', dayfirst=True)
    ...:     b = pd.to_datetime(mm_dates_base[col], errors='coerce', format='%d%b%Y')
    ...:     mm_dates_base[col] = a.combine_first(b)
    ...:     
5.13 ms ± 46.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)


In [43]: %%timeit
    ...: df1 = mm_dates_base[varlist2].apply(pd.to_datetime, errors='coerce', dayfirst=True)
    ...: df2 = mm_dates_base[varlist2].apply(pd.to_datetime, errors='coerce', format='%d%b%Y')
    ...: 
    ...: mm_dates_base[varlist2] = df1.combine_first(df2)
    ...: 
14.1 ms ± 92.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: I prefer your second solution since I don't like to assume the only other type of format I'll encounter with my source data is `%d%b%Y`. Could this work with even more formats, like for example, if I wanted to add `c=...` for something else that to_datetime failed to convert the first time round? How would the next like then change?

Comment: Then only use `mm_dates_base[col] = a.combine_first(b).combine_first(c)`

Comment: Right. Okay, so I ran that loop and it looks like d_start was converted but obs_date wasn't. Any ideas why?

Comment: @Aaraeus - It is not converted by `b = pd.to_datetime(mm_dates_base[col], errors='coerce', format='%d%b%Y')` ? It should be.

Answer (score 0):

The `to_datetime` function will usually detect what format the date is when converting, but the lack of spaces in your `d_start` and `obs_date` are probably what are causing the error. You might have to run a `.strptime()` on those specific values/columns. You'll have to look into this, but from the looks of it it'll follow something like `%d%b%Y`.